# How to sum certain index in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have an array.

`[ '219_1_undefined',  '244_1_undefined',  '248_1_20///179+25///153',  '221_6_undefined' ]`

Breakdown for a single item in the array goes by `219_1_undefined` basically is `219` is `product_id`, `1` is the quantity and `undefined` is the `product_options` I'm storing these information in local storage. Now I have a new item that needs to be added to the cart, but this product is already in cart so I want to add the quantity alone (middle value). So I want to add `219_1_undefined` again to the existing array. Now the array will be look like this.

`[ '219_1_undefined',  '244_1_undefined',  '248_1_20///179+25///153',  '221_6_undefined', '219_1_undefined' ]`

My problem is I don't know how to add the middle value(quantity) of the same product and get result like

`[ '244_1_undefined',  '248_1_20///179+25///153',  '221_6_undefined', '219_2_undefined' ]`

Below is the code I tried

```js
let pid = 219;
let qty = 1;
let params = "undefined";

let string = '219_1_undefined|244|1_undefined|248_1_20///179+25///153|221_1_undefined';

let items = string.split('|');

 let nItem = pid+'_'+qty+'_'+params;
 let mx = items;
 mx = mx.filter(function (item) {
  return item.indexOf(pid+'_') !== 0;
  });
 mx.push(nItem);
 var result = mx.toLocaleString();
 let nresult = result.split(',').join('|');
      
 console.log(nresult);
```

No matter what I do I still get the wrong output.

Comment: That's a... strange format. Why don't you use an array of objects (`{ id: ..., options: ..., quantity: ... }`)?

Comment: Because I'm storing this array in local storage as string that's why

Comment: You already have to use `JSON.parse()` so throw in an additional `JSON.stringify()` and work with something more useful (like an array of objects)

Comment: Man I get it, this is my junior dev's issue the manager has assigned this to me This exact same format is being used in over for 6 - 7 pages that's very cumbersome for me to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try getting the *index* using [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and update the array item using that *index*:

```js
let pid = 219;
let qty = 1;
let params = "undefined";

let items = ['219_1_undefined', '244_1_undefined', '248_1_20///179+25///153', '221_1_undefined'];

//get the index of the item from the array by matching the id
let index = items.findIndex(p => p.split('_')[0] == pid);
//check if any item is exist in the array
if(index > -1){
  //using the index update the item in the array with the new value
  items[index] = pid + '_' + (+items[index].split('_')[1] + qty) + '_' + params;
}
else{
  //push new item to the arry
  items.push(pid + '_' + qty + '_' + params);
}

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let pid = 219;
let qty = 1;
let params = "undefined";

let string = '219_1_undefined|244|1_undefined|248_1_20///179+25///153|221_1_undefined';
let items = string.split('|');
let i = 0;

for(; i < items.length; i++) {
  let temp = items[i].split('_');
  if (temp[0] == pid && temp[2] == params) {
    qty = parseInt(qty) + parseInt(temp[1]);
    break;
  }
}

items[i] = `${pid}_${qty}_${params}`;
string = items.join('|');
```

I tested this and it appears to work.The if statement compares botht he ID and param, but obviously you can only have it check the ID if you want.